# worst case time for adding values to a hash table

Tags: hash-tables

A certain hash table uses external chaining, and is resized each time its load factor
exceeds 3. Also, if an addition does not cause the load factor to exceed 3, but does
cause some bucket to exceed 6 elements, the table is given a new hashing function
and the elements of the table are redistributed in accordance with this new function.
Suppose that (somehow) this new hashing function always happens to distribute the
existing keys evenly (≤ 3 per bucket) as long as the addition did not exceed the load
factor. If the table intially has B buckets and 2B values, **how long in the worst case
does it take to add an additional B values?** Assume that comparisons and the hash
functions all take constant time. 
I am not sure how to approach this problem

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  I notice that I've given  you similar feedback before: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145770/structural-induction-proofs-for-regular-expression#comment307732_145770